# Why don't the CRS rules in ModSecurity block all threats?

Tags: nginx, mod-security, ubuntu-20.04, owasp

I'm in the process of configuring the new `Ngnix v1.18.0` server together with `ModSecurity-nginx v1.0.1.` I've added `OWASP CRS 3.3.0` rules to the configuration. Unfortunately, I can't clearly tell if the rules are working. While reading blogs and articles about it I saw 3 possibilities to determine it:

`curl -H "User-Agent: Nobody" http://5x.xx.xx.xxx:8085`,
`curl http://5x.xx.xx.xxx:8085/?exec=/bin/bash`,
`curl -I 'http://5x.xx.xx.xxx:8085/?param="><script>alert(1);</script>' --insecurecle`.

None of these methods block access through code 403. I didn't notice any logs for these events while executing these commands.
The logs `/var/log/modsec_audit.log` actually contain some information that would indicate that CRS rules are working... What could be the reason for such action ?

The `modsec_audit.log` file contains reports like this:

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^[\d.:]+$' against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:Host' (Value: `51.83.131.157' ) [file "/usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "718"] [id "920350"] [rev ""] [msg "Host header is a numeric IP address"] [data "51.83.131.157"] [severity "4"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/210/272"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [hostname "5x.xx.xx.xxx"] [uri "/api/v1"] [unique_id "1603116449"] [ref "o0,13v27,13"]
```

My file main.conf:

```
# Include the recommended configuration
Include /etc/nginx/modsec/modsecurity.conf

# A test rule
SecRule ARGS:testparam "@contains test" "id:1234,deny,log,status:403"

# OWASP CRS v3.3.0 rules
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/crs-setup.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-901-INITIALIZATION.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-903.9001-DRUPAL-EXCLUSION-RULES.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-903.9002-WORDPRESS-EXCLUSION-RULES.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-903.9003-NEXTCLOUD-EXCLUSION-RULES.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-903.9004-DOKUWIKI-EXCLUSION-RULES.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-903.9005-CPANEL-EXCLUSION-RULES.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-903.9006-XENFORO-EXCLUSION-RULES.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-905-COMMON-EXCEPTIONS.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-910-IP-REPUTATION.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-911-METHOD-ENFORCEMENT.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-912-DOS-PROTECTION.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-913-SCANNER-DETECTION.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-921-PROTOCOL-ATTACK.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-930-APPLICATION-ATTACK-LFI.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-931-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RFI.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-932-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RCE.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-933-APPLICATION-ATTACK-PHP.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-934-APPLICATION-ATTACK-NODEJS.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-943-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SESSION-FIXATION.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-944-APPLICATION-ATTACK-JAVA.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/RESPONSE-950-DATA-LEAKAGES.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/RESPONSE-951-DATA-LEAKAGES-SQL.conf
Include /usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/RESPONSE-952-DATA-LEAKAGES-JAVA.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule `920350` was triggered, because you sent your request to an IP address, not to a host name. If your application doesn't have any DNS entry, make an entry in your `/etc/hosts` file, and set your server for that name. Then you have to sent your request like this: `curl http://your.dns.name:8085/?exec=/bin/bash` - if you get the status 403, and you see this in your log, then your engine works.

Note, that is your `SecRuleEngine` is set to `DetectOnly`, you will see the request and the results in your log, but you wont get 403. You must change this setting to `On`.